# Trigger email when credit card information updated by the customer - WooCommerce Subscription

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm using WooCommerce Subscription on my website.

I have a page where the customers can see their subscription information and have option to update their payment information like credit card information.

I use this code to display the subscription information:

SubscriptionWCS_Template_Loader::get_my_subscriptions();

[image]

What I want is, I want to trigger an email when the customer updated their card. Is there any hook available on WooCommerce Subscription? or any free plugin that has this feature?

Thanks in advance

I searched for a lot of time but couldn't find any article that explains this.
Also checked this but no luck.
https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to solve this and the hook you are looking for is

`add_action( 'after_woocommerce_add_payment_method', 'your_function_here');`